# Почему не показывает нужную кодировку из csv? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, decode

Загружаю csv файл в кодировке utf-8 (кодировку поставил через notepad++).

При открытии файла csv и  вывода строки показывает это:
Р”Р»РёРЅР°:РЎС‚Р°РЅРґР°СЂС‚РЅС‹Р№ (L)

а должен это:
*Длина:Удлиненный (L)*

```
with open("./xls/mainCSV_utf.csv") as f_obj:
   read_csv(f_obj)

def read_csv(f_obj)
  reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=';')
  for line in reader:
    print(line["value"])
```

Comment: Ну так вы питону забыли рассказать о том, что у файла кодировка utf-8, вот он и пытается читать в какой попало кодировке

Comment: кодировка стоит, в том то и дело

Comment: Нет, не стоит. Вот в ответе от Sergey Gornostaev стоит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать кодировку файла при его открытии

```
with open("./xls/mainCSV_utf.csv", encoding='utf-8') as f_obj:
```

или будет использована системная. В случае несовпадения системной с фактической, получите кракозябры.